# Muxing MP4 and AAC (jcodec, MP4Parser)

Tags: java, android, encoding, mp4parser, jcodec

I have an MP4 file that I generate with jcodec.

I then have an AAC file I generate with Android's MediaCodec.

I want to mux them together into a single file and since I don't want to limit my Android API too high, I'm opting for [MP4Parser](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser).

---

**Here's my current code:**

```
H264TrackImpl h264Track = new H264TrackImpl(new FileDataSourceImpl("input.mp4"));
AACTrackImpl aacTrack = new AACTrackImpl(new FileDataSourceImpl("input.aac"));

Movie movie = new Movie();
movie.addTrack(h264Track);
movie.addTrack(aacTrack);

Container mp4file = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(movie);

FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("output.mp4"));
FileChannel fc = fileOutputStream.getChannel();
mp4file.writeContainer(fc);
fileOutputStream.close();
```

---

**The code crashes at the line:**

```
H264TrackImpl h264Track = new H264TrackImpl(new FileDataSourceImpl("input.mp4"));
```

**With this as the stack trace:**

```
09-01 18:46:40.611: E/AndroidRuntime(14115): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 1260
09-01 18:46:40.611: E/AndroidRuntime(14115): Process: package.app, PID: 14115
09-01 18:46:40.611: E/AndroidRuntime(14115): java.lang.RuntimeException: Sequence parameter set extension is not yet handled. Needs TLC.
09-01 18:46:40.611: E/AndroidRuntime(14115):    at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.H264TrackImpl.readSamples(H264TrackImpl.java:362)
09-01 18:46:40.611: E/AndroidRuntime(14115):    at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.H264TrackImpl.parse(H264TrackImpl.java:108)
09-01 18:46:40.611: E/AndroidRuntime(14115):    at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.H264TrackImpl.<init>(H264TrackImpl.java:90)
09-01 18:46:40.611: E/AndroidRuntime(14115):    at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.H264TrackImpl.<init>(H264TrackImpl.java:96)
09-01 18:46:40.611: E/AndroidRuntime(14115):    at com.googlecode.mp4parser.authoring.tracks.H264TrackImpl.<init>(H264TrackImpl.java:100)
09-01 18:46:40.611: E/AndroidRuntime(14115):    at ...
```

(The crash occurs in [this function at this line](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser/blob/master/isoparser/src/main/java/com/googlecode/mp4parser/authoring/tracks/h264/H264TrackImpl.java#L349).)

---

So I'm not really sure what that means? Does jcodec output an MP4 file (which works in all video players btw) that isn't compatible with MP4Parser?

What should I be looking into to fix this?

Appreciate any advice.

---

Edit

Was going about it the wrong way, this worked

```
Movie movie = MovieCreator.build(_videoFile.getAbsolutePath());

AACTrackImpl aacTrack = new AACTrackImpl(new FileDataSourceImpl(_aacFile));
CroppedTrack aacCroppedTrack = new CroppedTrack(aacTrack, 1, aacTrack.getSamples().size());
movie.addTrack(aacCroppedTrack);

Container mp4file = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(movie);

FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(_outputFile);
FileChannel fc = fileOutputStream.getChannel();
mp4file.writeContainer(fc);
fileOutputStream.close();
```

Comment: Did you finally solve this?

Comment: @Patrick its been a while but I think the code I appended to the OP was the solution, was going about it the wrong way w/ wrong code

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me....

```
        DataSource videoFile = new FileDataSourceImpl(filePath);

        Movie sor = MovieCreator.build(videoFile);

        List<Track> videoTracks = sor.getTracks();
        Track h264Track = null;

        for (Track t : videoTracks
             ) {
            if(t.getHandler().contains("vid"))
            {
                h264Track = t;
```